# What's the difference between Super+Tab and Alt+Tab on Gnome?

Tags: gnome3, workspaces, alt-tab

I'm on Manjaro Gnome 3.28.3.

For my situation, they do same thing, list thumbnails of all opened applications and if you press <kbd>Super</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, Tab could help you to switch  the applications.

So, I want <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to do different things. Like <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> switch applications only on this workspace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, they appear to both be assigned to “Switch applications”. They can be re-assigned using the keyboard preferences:

1. Open the menu in the top-right-hand corner of your main screen.
2. Click on the “Settings button”, *i.e.* the left-most button here:

   [image: GNOME buttons]
3. Choose “Devices” in the left-hand column:

   [image: Screenshot of the settings window, showing “Devices” selected]
4. Choose “Keyboard”.

This will lead you to a list of supported keyboard shortcuts, with their assigned keys; you can click on any entry to change it:

[image: Screenshot of the settings window, showing the keyboard shortcuts]

The “Switch applications” entry is somewhat strange: it only shows <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, but it is also assigned to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and will be disabled if you re-assign the latter. However it can then be re-assigned to whatever you want. As you can see, I use <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch applications, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch windows, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch windows inside an application.

You can assign nearly any key to any of the supported shortcuts, but you can’t add new shortcuts.

On my system, running GNOME 3.26, “Switch windows“ only shows windows on the current workspace:

[image: Screenshot of the window switcher]

whereas “Switch applications” shows all applications across all workspaces:

[image: Screenshot of the application switcher]

Note that GNOME Tweaks has an “Alternatetab” extension which can also be used to adjust the behaviour of the window switcher.

Comment: Thanks, Kitt! On my system, `Alt+\`` do the same thing (meaning it is gnome default for my pc) you set `Ctrl+Super+Tab`. After I do the same setting about `Super+Tab` and `Alter+Tab`follow your instructions, `Alt+Tab`only windows on the current workspace, while `Super+Tab` show windows on all workspace. In my opinion, your last paragraph,“Switch windows“ and “Switch applications” only show windows on the current workspace means they do same thing.

Comment: Hi, I have a small question, how to print a word with these <kbd>surrounding</kbd>, just use `<kbd>`?

Comment: The workspace behaviour might well have changed between 3.26 and 3.28, on my system it feels like a bug ;-). Regarding my last paragraph, “switch windows” and “switch applications” don’t do the same thing: switching windows goes through each individual window, whereas switching applications only shows one window per application.

Comment: To get the keyboard formatting, yes, add a `<kbd>` tag before the key symbol, and a `</kbd>` closing tag after it.

Comment: Oh wait, I had “Alternatetab” set to only show windows on the current workspace, I’ll update my answer...

Answer (score 2):

Gnome 3.36 (Ubuntu 20.04):

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches **applications**, consolidating multiple windows into a single icon, and giving you the most-recently-used window if you let go on it.  It also shows only icons rather than representations of the contents of each window. It operates across workspaces (i.e., showing all open applications) and will shift the focus to another workspace to get you to the selected application.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches **windows**, showing you all the open windows in the current workspace only, as mini-representations of that window. So, more cluttered, but more specific.

Comment: It may be useful to know that Alt-\` switches between *windows of the current app*. Super-\` also does the same thing.